# Debug on GGTS 3.6.4.RELEASE can't inspect, throw exception: ContentTypeUtils.isGroovyLikeFileName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, ggts

I am working with GGTS

Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

Additionally, I download and configure to use Groovy Compiler 2.4.12 and Grails 2.5.1.

My problem is when I'am in debug mode and stop on a breakpoint and inspect anything I got exception:

> org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.util.ContentTypeUtils.isGroovyLikeFileName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

I googled it but I don't find anything.

I tried this already but doesn't work:

- Remote Debug
- Use Expressions View
- Use display to inspect/run code

I don't know if this is a common error in GGTS or if in another IDLES this work fine.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`ContentTypeUtils.isGroovyLikeFileName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z` has been replaced with `ContentTypeUtils.isGroovyLikeFileName(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z` in the 2.9.2 snapshots.  Grails tooling would need to be recompiled against the latest Groovy tooling to fix this.  Or the method signature would need to be reintroduced into the Groovy tooling.